# How do i disable a function in javascript when calling another function with onclick event?

Tags: javascript, slider

I am a beginner in javascript and have this problem. I have a slider that runs automatic when loading the window and i have also prev and next buttons. The problem is that when i click the buttons, the slider runs automatic over. How can i disable the function that makes my slide automatic when clicking the buttons?
here is my HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper"> 
    <img src = "images/slide/slide1.jpg" id="adSlide"/>
</div>



<div class="slider-button-wrapper" >
    <button type="button" value="previous" id="blackleft" onclick="processPrevious()" ><p>&lt;</p></button>
    <button type="button" value="next" id="blackright" onclick="processNext()"><p>&gt;</p></button>
</div>
```

And javascript code:

```
              window.onload = rotate;
     var thisSlide=0;

function rotate(){
var adImages = new Array("images/slide/slide1.jpg", 
                        "images/slide/slide2.jpg",
                        "images/slide/slide3.jpg",
                        "images/slide/slide4.jpg",
                        "images/slide/slide5.jpg");
thisSlide++;

if(thisSlide == adImages.length){
    thisSlide=0;
}

document.getElementById("adSlide").src = adImages[thisSlide];

setTimeout(rotate, 3 * 1000);
}



var myPics = new Array("images/slide/slide1.jpg", 
                        "images/slide/slide2.jpg",
                        "images/slide/slide3.jpg",
                        "images/slide/slide4.jpg",
                        "images/slide/slide5.jpg");

function initButtons(){
    document.getElementById("blackleft").onclick = processPrevious;
    document.getElementById("blackright").onclick = processNext;
}

 function processPrevious(){
     if (thisSlide == 0){
        thisSlide = myPics.length;
  }
    thisSlide--;
    document.getElementById("adSlide").src = myPics[thisSlide];
    return false;
}

 function processNext(){
    thisSlide ++;
    if (thisSlide == myPics.length){
    thisSlide = 0;
  }

   document.getElementById("adSlide").src = myPics[thisSlide];
   return false;
  }
```

Comment: As is, you cannot. You must take note of the timer id returned by setTimeout. Only then you'll be able to cancel the timer from your event handlers.

Comment: Put timeout in variable `var timer = setTimeout(rotate, 3 * 1000);` and in functions `processPrevious` and `processNext` add timeout cancel `timer.clearTimeout() ` and that will stop your timer

Comment: It worked! thanks!